# Why does my Pokemon Go app close back to homescreen every time I select a starter?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

Recently I've downloaded Pokemon Go on my Huaway Y360-u31.
The phone meets all the requirements of the game, except RAM. (Although on the Pokemon Go site RAM doesn't even stand in the list of requirements.)
Here's the problem:

I'm still stuck in the tutorial in which I need to choose a Pokemon. The game loads pretty quick and the starters appear. Unfortunately every time I click on a starter, or wait too long, the game crashes and I'm back in the homescreen of my phone.

Does anyone have a fix for the problem of not being able of catching the starter Pokemon? Location is turned on and is not the problem here.

Comment: This could easily be to do with the servers being overloaded with people playing Pokémon GO, why don't you try again early in the morning or late at night. (When the server is less busy.)

Comment: George I doubt that's the case, I've never had the actual app crash due to the server. It just disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone might not have enough RAM then try to limit the RAM being used for other apps. You didn't say what kind of phone you have, but if it's a smart phone, then you should have a way to view what processes are running and close everything that's not needed. There are also apps for Android (not sure about Apple) that will make this easier and also show how much RAM you have available. Restarting your phone right before playing might also help.

Unfortunately, Pokemon Go just doesn't work on some phones right now, even when they meet the technical requirements. You may have to wait for Niantic to fix some of their issues or get a new phone to play.